# Why no asm in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-sources

The asm source was apparently dropped in 16.04 (produces the libasm-java package.

Currently here on 16.04 asm 5.2 & 6.0 both build ok but i'd like to know the reason behind dropping. Usually i can track done the reason for source drops in Launchpad but this time can't find anything.

So if anyone can shed some light on this it would be most helpful.

Comment: If you look on [`packages.ubuntu.com`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libasm&searchon=names) you notice that Xenial has `libasm[234]-java` (no plain `libasm-java`), whereas Trusty has `libasm-java` plus `libasm[234]-java`, and Zesty, Artful and Bionic all have the plain `libasm-java` plus `libasm[34]-java` (no `libasm2-java`).

Comment: Those aren't from the asm source, they are from libasm4-java source, not quite the same.